Setting shared function values in parallel is running sequentially
I am trying to define a function whose values can be updated across different Kernels running in parallel, where each Kernel might have to use values defined by other Kernels previously in the process. I am trying to use SetSharedFunction to synchronize everything, and, while it seems like it is doing this, when I initially try defining the function it seems like the Kernels are running sequentially rather than in parallel at the same time.
Here is my test function, where the Pause[1] is being used to verify parallel computation and the Print function is being used to indicate if the function value is already defined or not:
ClearAll@test
SetSharedFunction[test]
test[a_] := test[a] = Block[{}, Pause[1]; Print["first" <> ToString[a]]; a];

When I use ParallelTable the first time, the process appears to run sequentially, taking 1 second per Kernel.
$KernelCount
ParallelTable[test[i], {i, $KernelCount}] // AbsoluteTiming

The above code gives the following output (ignoring the Print outputs, which pop up one at a time each second)
12
{12.2383, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}

Running again confirms the function values are indeed set
{0.0399947, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}

And it does look like the function is still defined across all kernels
ParallelTable[test[$KernelCount + 1 - i], {i, $KernelCount}] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.082705, {12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}}

So then, why does defining the function run sequentially? Am I setting this up incorrectly, or is that just how functions with SetSharedFunction work initially?
Is there a workaround to where the function values can all be set in parallel while also being shared across kernels?

You could do something like this:
LaunchKernels[4];
test[a_] := If[ IntegerQ[testShared[a]]
                , 
                  testShared[a]
                , 
                  testShared[a] = 
                  Block[{}, Pause[1]; 
                    Print[StringJoin[" first", ToString[a]]]; a]
]; 
SetSharedFunction[testShared]; 
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[test[i], {i, $KernelCount}]]
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[test[i], {i,$KernelCount}]]

The relevant sentence in the docs of SetSharedFunction is:

Expressions of the form f[...] evaluated on any parallel
subkernel are sent to the master kernel, where they are evaluated, and
the result is sent back to the parallel subkernel.

One should be able to use ValueQ[testShared[a]] instead of this more specific IntegerQ[testShared[a]], but that does not seem to work.
You could just call Wolfram Support to explain why this does not work.
Or maybe somebody else knows.

Awesome! I think this actually is all I need, although I need to do more until I actually get to apply it. My actual application outputs an association, and AssociationQ appears to work just like IntegerQ here, so I think it will work out!
